# Trouble with a small excerpt from Tanizaki's Himitsu

Tags: translation, parsing, relative-clauses, literature

I'm having some trouble understanding the following excerpt (from Tanizaki's *Himitsu*):

> 甘い匂いのひやひやとした露が、毛穴へ染み入る皮膚のよろこびは格別であった

"The sweet scented and chilly dew" does what? "the delight of the skin that penetrated the pores was exceptional"? Help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ［甘い匂いのひやひやとした露が、毛穴へ染み入る］皮膚のよろこびは格別であった。

甘い匂いのひやひやとした露が、毛穴へ染み入る is a relative clause modifying 皮膚.
The subject of 染み入る is 甘い匂いのひやひやとした露.

The sentence roughly means something like.....

> "The delight of the skin [into the pores of which the sweet scented and chilly dew penetrated] was exceptional" / "The delight of the skin [when the sweet scented and chilly dew penetrated its pores] was exceptional."